# exc_bad_access (code=1, address=0x2012

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am getting this error:

```
exc_bad_access (code=1, address=0x2012
```

when I try to receive a value from a singleton in this way:

```
Draggable* sharedSingleton = [Draggable sharedManagerDraggable];
NSLog(@"%@", sharedSingleton.namePassedToDraggable);
```

The code above is placed in the Draggable.m of type UIImageView, which also has:

```
+ (Draggable *)sharedManagerDraggable
{
static Draggable *sharedManagerDraggable = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedManagerDraggable = [[Draggable alloc] init];
});
return sharedManagerDraggable;
}
```

I assign a value to namePassedToDraggable in this way (from view controller.m):

```
#import Draggable.h

Draggable* sharedSingleton = [Draggable sharedManagerDraggable];
    sharedSingleton.namePassedToDraggable = txt.text;
        NSLog(@"%@", sharedSingleton.namePassedToDraggable);
    dragger.tag = img.tag;
```

And in Draggable.h I have:

```
+ (Draggable *) sharedManagerDraggable;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* namePassedToDraggable;
```

Why do I get the error causing the app to crash? I use the same method in other viewcontorllers and it works just fine!

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, assign)` should be `@property (nonatomic, strong)`...

Comment: I use the assign for passing numbers and it works, but I will try strong

Comment: I don't think `NSString *` refers to a number... -.-"

Comment: post an answer and i'll vote u up

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* namePassedToDraggable;
```

should be

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* namePassedToDraggable;
```

If the property is not `strong`, it's not retained and it's released at the end of the scope of the function in which you're assigning it.

Comment: Thank you! 5 more characters